# Heatmap in plotly with defined colors per category in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I am trying to plot a heatmap with specified colors (by category) in plotly. I asked a similar question here: ["Split" up by category in plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57824941/split-up-by-category-in-plotly).

However, I ran into a new problem while trying a similar thing with a heatmap. My code looks like:

```
# Test DataFrame
test_df <- data.frame(
  "weekday" = c("Fr", "Sa", "Su"),
  "time" = c("06:00:00", "12:00:00", "18:00:00"),
  "channel" = c("NBC", "CBS Drama", "ABC"),
  "colors" = c("#FCB711", "#162B48", "#AA8002"),
  "views" = c(1200, 1000, 1250)
)

plot_ly(colors = unique(as.character(test_df$colors)),  type = "heatmap") %>%
  add_trace(test_df,
        x = test_df$weekday,
        y = test_df$time,
        z = test_df$views,
        type = "heatmap")
```

What I get is the following picture:
[image]

The problems I have here are: 
1. The colors are not the colors which I told R to use 
2. I do not want a colorscale, rather the categories split up channels.

I know there is a workaround in ggplot, and I am working on it, but I want to have it in plotly. 
Here is what it looks like in ggplot and what I want to have in plotly (*I am aware of ggplotly, but that still isn't pure plotly*):
[image]

Here is the code for the above picture:

```
channel_colors <- test_df %>% distinct(colors) %>% pull(colors)
names(channel_colors) <- test_df %>% distinct(channel) %>% pull(channel)

p <- ggplot(data = test_df,
            aes(
              x = weekday,
              y = time,
              fill = channel)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(alpha = views)) +
  scale_alpha(range = c(0.5, 1)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = channel_colors) 

ggplotly(p)
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: As you describe it, it almost sounds like a heatmap is not what your're looking for. Do you want colors to indicate channels ***only***? Where would you like to illustrate the number of views then?

Comment: That is in fact a bit more difficult. The number of views shall be the "brightness" of the color from the channel. Do you have any ideas?